# Create a Map with keys from 1 to 100 odd numbers and Values ​from even numbers from 1 to 100 in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dictionary

Thanks in advance! It's the first time I am asking in StackOverflow

Comment: How to associate keys with values? 1 -> 2, 3 -> 4 and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Keys and values in ascending order:

```
val result = (1..100 step 2).associateWith { it + 1 }

println(result)   // prints {1=2, 3=4, 5=6, 7=8, ..., 99=100}
```

If you need only the keys in ascending order and the values shuffled:

```
val result = (1..99 step 2)
  .zip((2..100 step 2).shuffled())
  .toMap()

println(result)   // {1=74, 3=18, 5=40, 7=14, 9=76, 11=34, ..., 99=38}
```

If you need both the keys and the values shuffled:

```
val result = (1..99 step 2).shuffled()
  .zip((2..100 step 2).shuffled())
  .toMap()

println(result)   // {23=34, 39=70, 61=24, 77=36, 83=86, ..., 49=74}
```